# Managing Git Versions and Branches to Correspond with 3rd Party Versioned Software

Tags: git

I'm building an open-source client for another open-source software. The third-party software versions their releases with tags like 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, etc. These versions are all merged back into master, any patches to their software just increase that versioning, so there's currently no concept of patching multiple major versions.

In those changing versions, that are some significant differences in their code that represent fairly substantial differences in the code I need in the client. So my client that supports 1.0 will likely have some incompatible differences with the client that can support version 1.1, though they'll share a majority of the code base. I'll also need to patch each version of the client as I find bugs/improvements. Sometimes that patch may affect each version of the client, maybe sometimes only 1 version. So although I may be working on version 2.1 of the client (corresponding to version 2.1 of the third-party software), I may have to go back and release a 1.1.1 patch to the original 1.1 client version (hope that all makes sense).

I'm trying to figure out what strategy to use with Git (I'm working in Visual Studio and GitHub) to support this. Right now I'm leaning towards creating a branch from master for each release of the software, updating the code to be compatible with the new release, then merging that back into master, and tagging each commit in each branch with a specific patch version number. This should allow me to check out a specific branch version to update, commit, and repackage for deployment. I don't think it handles updating something though that is still common throughout each branch, so I'd need to perform the update in each branch (and obviously commit new tag versions for each).

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to split it into a "core" project and a "version-specific" project, if either (a) it's predictable which parts of the code will vary from version to version, or (b) you can structure the code in a way that allows a version in the version-specific project to override any given part of the core project behavior.  It's not a perfect solution - and I'm not sure there is one - but it would ease some of the problem you describe.